# Google Cloud Datastore backup - deprecated?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

since yesterday I dont have the option to back up my Google AppEngine datastore using the datastore admin on AppSpot.com.

on the new console.developer.google.com there is no option to backup your AppEngine, or at least none that I noticed.

can you please check?

[image: Appspot.com console]

Answer (score 3):

It is still accessible through the new Developer Console, under **Storage** > Cloud Datastore > Settings.

Or just go to `https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your-project-id>/datastore/settings`

Answer (score 0):

Datastore Admin backups are now deprecated in favor of the managed export and import feature, which can be accessed through gcloud or the Datastore Admin API:

[Exporting and Importing Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities)

[Scheduling an Export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export)